# Clean image before OCR?

Tags: android, c, image-processing, ocr, renderscript

**Before** 
[image]

**After**
[image]

I found a spectacular example demonstrate how to clear image before OCR, I think much about it and try to analyze it, **It was awesome**.

- Compare with original image , the processed image has :

  - Remove background and unrelated objects
  - Remove flash radiance
  - Enhance text
  - Scale image to fit the content.

Does anybody know how do this ? I mean which steps ? (grey, scale, threshold,...)
Thank for your reading

Answer (score 0):

Looks like simple segmentation using the color of the text.

Comment: nope, actually they use SWT, I found this solution here, but still not  find Android implementation      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837124/stroke-width-transform-swt-implementation-java-c